# Update a record on the fly while checking using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I want to check my IEnumerable list if it contains something and update it on the fly.

What I am doing right now:

```
private bool IsPointValid(Point point, IEnumerable<CustomRectangle> rectangles)
{
    return rectangles.Any(r => r.Rectangle.Contains(point) && !r.IsChecked);
}
```

My code checks properly for everything, but my problem is, how to change the value of `IsChecked` after finishing the overall check so next time the function is called, the `IsChecked` value is updated properly.

Comment: Where is your data coming from? What is the context? See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) as well on how to ask a question

Comment: `var bob = rectangles.FirstOrDefault(r => r.Rectangle.Contains(point) && !r.IsChecked); if (bob != null) { bob.IsChecked = true; } return bob != null;`

Comment: Which one's need to be updated?  Just the ones where the point is in the rectangle, or all of them.  Either way Linq is not meant for mutating collections and I'd suggest you just use a `foreach` loop instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change your method to the following:

```
private bool IsPointValid(Point point, IEnumerable<CustomRectangle> rectangles)
{
     var firstMatch = rectangles.FirstOrDefault(r => r.Rectangle.Contains(point) && !r.IsChecked);

     if (firstMatch != null)
         firstMatch.IsChecked = true;

     return firstMatch != null; 
}
```

Comment: this will set property of only first match, what if there may multiple such Points (however in case of rectangle it doesn't seem likely, but for general case) ?

Answer (score 0):

from your question it seems you want something like this,

suppose you have a list of object (say of class Demo)

```
public class Demo
{
    public string Name;
    public bool flag;
    public Demo(string Name, bool flag)
    {
        this.Name = Name;
        this.flag = flag;
    }
}
```

and you are checking if this list contains some elements which have specific value and also updating other value.

```
List<Demo> list = new List<Demo>();
list.Add(new Demo("amit", false));

//Note here we are also setting x.flag to true with checking conditions 
if(list.Any(x => x.Name == "amit"  && !x.flag && (x.flag = true)))
{

}
```

here once flow goes inside of if, flag will be set to true.

EDIT

if there may multiple entries in the list which satisfy the same criteria (condition of checking), above code will update only first of them. If you want to update all of them do below code.

```
//here too we are setting flag to true, 
//but for all those objects which satisfy conditions
if(list.Where(x => x.Name == "amit" && !x.flag).Select(y => (y.flag=true)).Count() > 0)
{

}
```

Comment: You'd really want to comment that heavily since **many** people would overlook what `x.flag = true` is doing.

Comment: @mjwills thanks for pointing that out. I have added a comment there